# Get User details from Session in Spring Security

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to Spring MVC and Spring Security. I have performed log-in and registration functionality using Spring security and MVC. I am not able to find any way for session management .

I want to access some user details on all the pages like (email, name,id,role etc).
I want to save these to session object so I can get these on any of the page.

I get the following way for session in spring

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); 
auth.getPrincipal();
```

But from the object returned by this I can get only username and password details.

But I need to access more details of that user.

- Is there any way to do this by saving it to session and the get on the jsp page?
- or is there any OOTB way in spring to get this done?

Please help me to get solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

I want to get my model class object to be returned from SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails(); For this what I need to configure.

Regards,
Pranav

Comment: If you got the username couldn't you query by username? I'm assuming the table you're using to hold user info has username in it (which is unique). Query that and map to User model object by hand or through ORM.

Answer (score 9):

You need to make your model class implement the [UserDetails](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) interface

```
class MyUserModel implements UserDetails {
    //All fields and setter/getters

    //All interface methods implementation
}
```

Then in your spring controller you can do this:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
Object myUser = (auth != null) ? auth.getPrincipal() :  null;

if (myUser instanceof MyUserModel) {
     MyUserModel user = (MyUserModel) myUser;    
     //get details from model object        
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this to get the `UserDetails` (or any implementation with your custom details).

```
UserDetails userDetails = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();
```

If there are not available, you can load the user details from the [`UserDetailsService`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html).

In both cases, I think you have to save them yourself in a session scope bean.

Comment: I want to get my model class object to be returned from SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails(); For this what I need to configure